# django regroup and than dictsort by list length

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to regroup a list, than to show the results ordered by the number of items per result's list.

something like this:

```
{%  regroup car_models by make as car_models_by_make %}

{% for make in car_models_by_make|dictsort:"???" --> the problem %}
    {{ make.grouper }}  ({{ make.list|length }}) <br>
{% endfor %}
```

so if the data is:

```
[
('panda','fiat'),
('500','fiat'),
('focus','ford')
]
```

the result should be:

```
fiat 2
ford 1
```

I tried: dictsort:"make.list.count","make.list.length","make.list|length" .. none did the work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this template tags I've made:

```
@register.filter()
def groups_sort(groups):

    groups.sort(key=lambda group: len(group['list']))
    return groups

@register.filter()
def groups_sort_reversed(groups):
    groups.sort(key=lambda group: len(group['list']), reverse=True)
    return groups
```

It is possible to do this:

```
{% load custom_templatetags %}
{%  regroup car_models by make as car_models_by_make %}

{% for make in car_models_by_make|groups_sort_reversed %}
    {{ make.grouper }}  ({{ make.list|length }}) <br>
{% endfor %}
```

will give you

```
fiat 2
ford 1
```

Using groups_sort will give you:

```
ford 1
fiat 2
```

this of course works on Django Models too

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `dictsort` is fit here.

```
>>> l = [('panda', 'fiat'), ('500', 'fiat'), ('focus', 'ford')]
>>> values = [i[1] for i in l]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(values)
>>> c.most_common()
[('fiat', 2), ('ford', 1)]
```

You can define your own [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/),

```
from django import template
from collections import Counter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def my_sort(l):
    values = [i[1] for i in l]
    c = Counter(values)
    return c.most_common()
```

Comment: thanks imom0. are you sure there isnt a better solution? if no ill must accept yours..

Comment: @YardenST Sorry, I'm not sure, but "done is better than prefect". If you use `dictsort`, argument must be a key of dict.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your data to the template as a sorted list of dicts:

```
>>> data = [ ('panda','fiat'),
... ('500','fiat'),
... ('focus','ford') ]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby

# note that we need to sort data before using groupby
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x:x[1])

# make the generators into lists
>>> group_list = [(make, list(record)) for make, record in groups]

# sort the group by the number of car records it has
>>> sorted_group_list = sorted(group_list, key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)

# build the final dict to send to the template
>>> sorted_car_model = [{'make': make, "model": r[0]} for (make, records) in sorted_group_list for r in records]
>>> sorted_car_model
[{'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'panda'}, {'make': 'fiat', 'model': '500'}, {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'focus'}]
```

The goal here is to sort the list such that the car makers are ranked by the numbers of models they produce.

then, use:

```
{% regroup car_models by make as make_list %}

{% for item in make_list %}
    {{ item.grouper }} ({{ item.list|length }}) <br>
{% endfor %}
```

to get:

```
fiat 2
ford 1
```

---

Referece: [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup)

---

If your data looks like the one you have in your comments:

```
>>> car_models = [ 
...     {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'focus'},
...     {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'panda'},
...     {'make': 'ford', 'model': '500'},
...     {'make': 'fiat', 'model': '500'},
...     {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
...     {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
...     {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
... ] 
>>> 
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(car_models, key=lambda x:x['make']), key=lambda x:x['make'])
>>> groups = [(make, list(x)) for make, x in groups]
>>> sorted_group_list = sorted(groups, key=lambda x:len(x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> sorted_car_model = [{'make': make, 'model': r['model']} for (make, records) in sorted_group_list for r in records]

>>> sorted_car_model
[{'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'}, {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'}, {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'}, {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'panda'}, {'make': 'fiat', 'model': '500'}, {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'fo
cus'}, {'make': 'ford', 'model': '500'}]
```

---

Alternatively, you can just pass the results to the template like follows:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [r['make'] for r in car_models]
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> result = [{k: v} for k,v in dict(c).iteritems()]
>>> result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x.values(), reverse=True)
[{'opel': 3}, {'fiat': 2}, {'ford': 2}]
```

Then, pass this result to the template and simply just render the results instead:

```
{% for r in result %}
    {% for k,v in r.items %}
        {{ k }} {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}j
{% endfor %}
```

you will then get:

```
opel 3
fiat 2
ford 2
```

Comment: This doesn't sort the results by group's list's length..
consider:   
 car_models = [
    {'make': 'ford', 'model': 'focus'},
    {'make': 'fiat', 'model': 'panda'},
    {'make': 'ford', 'model': '500'},
    {'make': 'fiat', 'model': '500'},
    {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
    {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
    {'make': 'opel', 'model': '500'},
    
]

Comment: @YardenST ah yes you are right, I forgot the you wanted the a sorted one. I will update the answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks, it is not a complete answer though i wanted to only use template tags (to separate view from code). But thank you very much for your help. I'll make a good working templatetag to encapsulate all this and will publish the code here.

Comment: @YardenST You are welcome! I thought about it more and I think it makes lots of sense too in many cases :)