# django filter and order foreign-foreignkey in a query

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking for a solution to filter and order foreign key of the foreign key of my model.

Let's say I have:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)

class Songbook(models.Model):
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

I'm already able thanks to annotation to sort my songbook query by song count:

```
context['popular_songbooks_list'] = Songbook.objects.annotate(
        favoritesongbook_count=Count('favoritesongbook')).order_by('-favoritesongbook_count')[:10]
```

Now, I would like to display only the 3 main author contained in each songbook and I didn't find how to do it. Is there a solution using query or do I have to do a post-processing on the query list?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an easy way to do it inside the view by annotating the query, but thanks to this  post ([django regroup and than dictsort by list length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002919/django-regroup-and-than-dictsort-by-list-length)) I find a way to rich my goal.

Here is the solution :

From the popular_songbooks_list I showed in my first post, I use the regroup tag in template with custom filter and then slice to 3.

```
{% regroup songbook.songs.all by author as author_list %}
{% for author in author_list|groups_sort_reversed|slice:":3" %}
    {{ author.grouper }}
{% endfor %}
```

The custom tag :

```
@register.filter()
def groups_sort_reversed(groups):
    groups.sort(key=lambda group: len(group['list']), reverse=True)
    return groups
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it work !